# How do to make a stopwatch thread?

Tags: java, android

```
        //make timer
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;
        final TextView timer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer1);
        timer1.setText(min + ":" + sec);
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                sec+=1;
                if (sec>59) {
                    min+=1;
                    sec=0;
                }
                timer1.setText(min + ":" + sec);
                Log.d("Timer", "run: "+min+":"+sec);
                try
                {
                    sleep(1000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {}
            }
        };
        t.start();
```

i tried to create this thread which supposed to count number each second and update it in the textview,
but it just freeze when i run the activty.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a loop, adding a while loop is what makes the Thread keep running the code over and over and over.

Also you will not be able to update a TextView's text from a background thread.

i.e. `timer1.setText(min + ":" + sec);`

You will need to post the update, like so:

```
private boolean running = false;

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    final Handler mainThreadHandler = new Handler()
    running = true;
        // make timer
        min = 0;
        sec = 0;
        final TextView timer1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timer1);
        timer1.setText(min + ":" + sec);
        Thread t = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
               while(running) {
                  sec += 1;
                  if (sec > 59) {
                     min += 1;
                     sec = 0;
                  }
                  mainThreadHandler.post(new Runnable(){ 
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                           timer1.setText(min + ":" + sec);
                      }
                  }
                  Log.d("Timer", "run: "+min+":"+sec);
                  try{ Thread.sleep(1000);}
                  catch (InterruptedException e) {Log.e("TUT", "error! don't ignore me", e}
               } 
            }
        };
        t.start();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    running = false;
    super.onPause()
}
```